# How to git svn tag just some folders?

Tags: svn, tags, git-svn, trunk

I've a standard svn repo:

- branches/
- tags/

  - 0.1/
  - 0.2/
- trunk/

  - devops/
  - code/

and i want to tag *devops* and *code* folders into *tags/0.3* by git-svn.
Use of `git svn tag 0.3` instead creates a new tag with all the repo inside, including *tags* and *branches*. How can i exclude them?

Comment: Did you use `--stdlayout` when doing `git svn clone`? What does `ls` show in your git clone, is it `branches`, `tags`, `trunk`?

Comment: I just did `git svn clone` and yes, branches tags trunk as result of `ls`

Answer (score 0):

Please see [`man git-svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).

For svn repos in the "standard layout" (which means, `branches/` `tags/` `trunk/` like you have), you should pass `--stdlayout`/`-s` to `git svn clone`.

This will have the effect of mapping svn "branches" and "tags" to git branches; and svn trunk will become the master branch in git.

The expected working tree content in git repo for your example is this:

```
.
├── code
├── devops
└── .git
```